# How do I use booleans to create dataframe and plot the filtered data on pie chart?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {'City': ['KUMASI', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA', 'KUMASI', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA', 'ACCRA'], 'Building': ['Commercial', 'Commercial', 'Industrial', 'Commercial', 'Industrial', 'Commercial', 'Commercial', 'Commercial', 'Commercial'], 'LPL': ['NC', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'C', 'NC', 'NC', 'NC'], 'Lgfd': ['NC', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'C', 'NC', 'NC', 'C'], 'Location': ['NC', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'NC'], 'Hazard': ['NC', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'C', 'C', 'NC', 'NC'], 'Inspection': ['NC', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'NC', 'NC', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'Name': ['Zonal', 'In Prog', 'Tullow Oil', 'XGI', 'Food Factory', 'MOH', 'EV', 'CSD', 'Electroland'], 'Air Termination System': ['Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Early Streamer Emission', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Vertical Air Termination', 'Early Streamer Emission'], 'Positioned Using': ['Highest Points', 'Software', 'Software', 'Software', 'Highest Points', np.nan, np.nan, 'Rolling Sphere Method', 'Software']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Filter dataset to return rows with LPL being "C" and Hazard being "C"
filter = df[(df["LPL"] == "C") & (df["Hazard"] == "C")]

#Show number of rows in filter
print(filtered_1["LPL"].value_counts())
print(filtered_1["Hazard"].value_counts())
```

Now what I want to do is to plot a pie chart with two labels.
One label will be `LPL and Hazard being C` and another label will be `LPL and Hazard not being C`.

Essentially, what I mean is, the percentage of `LPL and Hazard being C` with respect to the total number of rows will be displayed on the chart and the same for `LPL and Hazard not being C`. Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I know is to compute the length of the full dataframe and the filtered one:

```
LPL_and_hazard_equal_C = len(filtered)
total_records = len(df)
LPL_and_harard_different_from_C = total_records - LPL_and_hazard_equal_C


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pie([LPL_and_hazard_equal_C, LPL_and_harard_different_from_C], labels = ['LPL and Hazard being C', 'LPL and Hazard not being C'], autopct = '%.1f%%')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe add something like `plt.pie(..., autopct="%.1f")`?